# Send predefined list of messages to multiple users using pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, python-multithreading, py-telegram-bot-api

I have to send mupltiple messages to multiple users. Some of messages should "wait" until user clicks button under that message. It should looks like that (from another more general [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67347889/send-chain-of-messages-to-multiple-users-using-pytelegrambotapi)):

```
>>> bot: 'Hello'
>>> bot: 'My name is %bot name%'
>>> bot: 'How are you?'
<<< button: 'Fine'  # <-- this is button. Any message should not to be sent before the user clicks `Fine` button
>>> bot: 'Can we continue?'  # <-- this message shows only after user clicks `Fine` button
<<< button: 'Yes'  # <-- this is button. Any message should not to be sent before the user clicks `Yes` button
>>> bot: 'That\'s great!'  # <-- this message shows only after user clicks `Yes` button
<<< button: 'Of course'  # <-- this is button. Any message should not to be sent before the user clicks `Of course` button
>>> bot: 'See you next time'  # <-- this message shows only after user clicks `Yes` button
```

I tried to implement that behaviour with generators without any success.

Now I'm ready to hardcode that pipelines but I still can't do this.

Minimal working example below:

```py
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Dict, List
from config import Config

import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(Config().get_str('test_bot_token'))


users: List[int] = []


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def _start(message: telebot.types.Message):
    users.append(message.chat.id)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda x: 'exec' in x.text)
def _send_message(message: telebot.types.Message):
    for i, user in enumerate(users):
        try:
            _send_message_to_user(user)
        except telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException as telegramEx:
            print(f'chat_id:{user}\t{telegramEx}')


def _send_message_to_user(user_id: int):
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda x: 'step_1' in x.data)
    def exec_step_2(query: telebot.types.CallbackQuery):
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=user_id,
                                      message_id=query.message.id,
                                      reply_markup=None)
        step_kb = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        step_kb.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Yes', callback_data='step_2'))
        bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id,
                         text='Can we continue?',
                         reply_markup=step_kb)
        time.sleep(1.25)

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda x: 'step_2' in x.data)
    def exec_step_2(query: telebot.types.CallbackQuery):
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=user_id,
                                      message_id=query.message.id,
                                      reply_markup=None)
        step_kb = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        step_kb.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('Of course', callback_data='step_3'))
        bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id,
                         text='That\'s great!',
                         reply_markup=step_kb)
        time.sleep(1.25)

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda x: 'step_3' in x.data)
    def exec_step_2(query: telebot.types.CallbackQuery):
        bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=user_id,
                                      message_id=query.message.id,
                                      reply_markup=None)
        bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id,
                         text='See you next time')
        time.sleep(1.25)

    bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text='Hello')
    time.sleep(1.25)

    bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text='My name is %bot name%')
    time.sleep(1.25)

    kb = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    kb.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Fine', callback_data='step_1'))
    bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text='How are you?', reply_markup=kb)


bot.polling()
```

The problem occures when more than one users attaches to the bot. First user gets full pipeline but second — doesn't get any message.

Easiest way to reproduce:

1. don't start the bot
2. send `/start` command to the bot
3. send two `exec` messages to the bot
4. start the bot

You will get two Hello, My name is %bot name%, How are you? messages. If you click any button `Fine` (first or second) you'll see `Loading...` message in the top of the chat and will not get any response.

But if you send `/start` command and single `exec` message everything will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to pyTelegramBotAPI [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/#asynctelebot)
on the AsyncTeleBot section

you can use async and await to make the bot work asynchronous.

change

```
import telebot
```

to

```
from telebot.async_telebot import AsyncTeleBot
import asyncio
```

and replace all `def` contains process code with `async def` example:

```
async def exec_step_2
```

then wrap all bot.send_message with await like this:

```
await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id,text='See you next time')
```

Hope it solve your problem